# VS code does not show my Conda Python 2 environments

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, conda

I am using ssh to connect to my remote server.
When I open my Jupyter notebook on VS code, all my python 2 conda environments are disappeared in the kernel.
[VS code kernels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJwSv.png)

The question is: how to show my python 2 conda environments on the VS code kernel?

- I double check in the terminal - the environments are still there. I also tried to create a new python 2 environment but still, it won't show on VS code.
  [terminal conda environments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4dVA.png)
- I also opened the Jupyter notebook on browser. It does have python 2 environment. Just not show in the VS code.
- I do have python 2 on my MBA (A1 chip) and also on my remove server (ubuntu).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now VsCode python Debug and Jupyter-NoteBook **don't support** Python versions **minor than  3.7.**

Please **UPDATE** your Python version.

Read the [announcement](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/Using-unsupported-Python-Environments) for more details.

Comment: Thank you. I have the latest VsCode and I will downgrade it to another version.

Comment: Yes and thank you. My old laptop has older version VsCode - which supports python 2.7.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. This is my first question on Stack Overflow. I just learned how to accept the answer and your answer is accepted. :)